# How to return the value from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have used the jquery ajax for getting the values from the server.when the method goes into the ajax success or error, i need to return the value.How to do that.Please guide me.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    type: "GET",
    timeout:6000,
    dataType: "json",
    url:url +"log",
    data: { ContactEmail : $("#username").val()},
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) 
    {
        //Here I need to return the result and should get in another method
    },
    Error: function (e)
    {
        //Here I need to return the result and should get in another method
    }
});
```

**update**

**for example**
when i called the **checkNetConnection()** ,it **return** the value.i need like this

```
function checkNetConnection() 
{
        var netresult=0;
        var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
        if(states[networkState]=='Ethernet connection'||states[networkState]=='WiFi connection' || states[networkState]=='Cell 2G connection' || states[networkState]=='Cell 3G connection' || states[networkState]=='Cell 4G connection')
        {
            netresult=1;
        }
        else
        {
            netresult=0;
        }
        return netresult;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results are stored in variables `result` and `e`:

```
...
success: function (result) 
    {
        // result contains the results
        foo( results );
    },
    Error: function (e)
    {
        // e contains the error
        bar( e );
    }
...

// Function to do something with the returned results
function foo( someData ) {
  // do stuff
}

// Function to do something with the error
function bar( someErrorData ) {
  // do stuff
}
```

A quick way of seeing the data is to display it using alert: `alert( results )` or `alert( e )` instead of the function calls.

Comment: @JavaH AJAX automatically returns you a value. Do you want to display a result or what?

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of issues with your code. You have specified `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"` but you are not sending JSON request. If you want to send a JSON request use the `JSON.stringify` method on your data:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ ContactEmail : $("#username").val() }),
```

If not, remove this contentType, otherwise it is ambiguous for the server. Another issue with your code is that the error callback is called `error`, not `Error`. And as far as fetching the results is concerned, inside the success callback they will be passed directly as argument:

```
success: function (result) {
    // Here I need to return the result and should get in another method
    anotherMethod(result);
},
```

It should also be noted that the argument passed to the success method will automatically be parsed by jQuery to the underlying type if your web server set the correct content type response header. So for example if your server set `Content-Type: application/json` and wrote `{"foo":"bar"}` to the response body, you can directly manipulate this object: `alert(result.foo);` inside this callback without additional parsing. If your web server script is poorly written and doesn't set the proper content type header, for example it sets `Content-Type: 'text/html'` and write a JSON formatted string into the response body, you have the possibility to force jQuery to parse to JSON using the `dataType: 'json'` parameter. But normally, if everything is correct you shouldn't need to do that.

Now, the `error` callback is different. It is passed the `xhr` object as argument, so you will have to extract the result as string this time:

```
error: function(xhr) {
    anotherMethod(xhr.getResponseText());    
}
```

If this string represents JSON you could parse it:

```
error: function(xhr) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(xhr.getResponseText());
    anotherMethod(result);    
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. AJAX is asynchronous, meaning that you cannot return anything from a function using an AJAX request. The only place where you can consume the results of this AJAX request is inside the success callback. That's something absolutely fundamental that every web developer doing AJAX development must know. If you don't understand this fundamental principal, I invite you to read more about what AJAX is and how it works.

Comment: If you want to perform an AJAX request inside the `checkNetConnection` you will have to modify it so that this function doesn't return anything. It should take 2 parameters: one representing a success callback and one representing the error callback. This way, anyone calling this function will be able to subscribe to those callbacks in order to handle the results. When doing asynchronous programming such as AJAX you should think in terms of callbacks and events, not in terms of return values.

Answer (score 0):

In the success method `result` is a json object which contains the data you sent from your server.

Use `console.log(result)` to see the data.

```
            success: function (result) 
            {
              console.log(result);
            },
            Error: function (e)
            {
            //Here I need to return the result and should get in another method
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  success: function (result) 
            {

              alert(result.someobject); //someobject is returned by your JSON
            },
```